# How to Bulkify the following code:

Tags: apex, bulkification

```
public void UncheckAllrecords(){
        getAgencyNameList();

        for(Agency_Name__c agencyuse : agencylistRec){
            System.debug(agencyName.ID +' - '+ agencyuse.ID);
             if(agencyuse.Is_Display_Name__c && agencyName.ID != agencyuse.ID){
                 agencyuse.Is_Display_Name__c = false;
                 system.debug('uncheck:'+agencyuse.Is_Display_Name__c);
                 Update agencyuse;
             } 
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Here is a link that explain why bulkify is important and other tips that every developer/admin should apply, or at least, know. I encourage you to read it, don't hesitate to go a bit further !
See for example https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Answer (score 2):

Create a new list which will hold only the changed records and at the end of for loop update that list.

```
public void UncheckAllrecords(){
        getAgencyNameList();

        // New list to hold the changed agency records
        List<Agency_Name__c> agencyListToUpdate = new  List<Agency_Name__c>();

        for(Agency_Name__c agencyuse : agencylistRec){
            System.debug(agencyName.ID +' - '+ agencyuse.ID);
             if(agencyuse.Is_Display_Name__c && agencyName.ID != agencyuse.ID){
                 agencyuse.Is_Display_Name__c = false;
                 system.debug('uncheck:'+agencyuse.Is_Display_Name__c);
                 agencyListToUpdate.add(agencyuse); // Add the changed record to list
                 //Update agencyuse;
             } 
        }  
        update  agencyListToUpdate;
    }
```